# How can I escape XML field in XML-output query?

Tags: postgresql, xml

I have following request:

```
SELECT XMLAGG(data) FROM
(SELECT XMLELEMENT(name item, XMLFOREST(
   title,
   body as description,
   date_created as date,
   'http://example.com/news'||id as link 
)) AS data FROM NEWS) AS smthng;
```

The issue is that body is actually XML itself, so the question is - 
How can I escape XML field (changing `<` to `&lt;` `>` to `&gt;` etc.) in this query?

Answer (score 1):

The naive approach would be to wrap your query around another `SELECT` and use `replace`.

```
SELECT replace(
    (SELECT XMLAGG(data) FROM
         (SELECT XMLELEMENT(name item, XMLFOREST(
          title,
          body as description,
          date_created as date,
          'http://example.com/news'||id as link 
         )
     ) AS data FROM NEWS) AS smthng)::text, '<', '&lt;')
```

And do the same for `>`. A easier and more elgant mthod would be to to it with the language that should deliver/process/... the XML.

Comment: I can write something like

` SELECT replace(XMLSERIALIZE(CONTENT body as VARCHAR),'"','&quot;') from news;
`
and so on. This is quite naive as well. It's a pity if there is no more handy language, since anything else related to XML output fits just perfect to me.